# Track other versions change with Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a few components and some projects using them. All the dependency management is done using maven. I'd like jenkins to check if code changes for a component would impact a project even if the project isn't using the newest version of it.
Let's say I have component foo, and projects bar and baz.

project_bar uses component_foo version 1.0.0
project_baz uses component_foo version 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT

While I'm changing component_foo version 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT so it can be used by project_baz I'd like to know if it could break project_bar build.
Being able to ignore a major version change (don't check compatibility if component_foo new version was 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT) would be a bonus but not required.

Answer (score 0):

There is on magical way in Jenkins to do that.

This is something handled by compiling the projects with the new dependecy version. To ensure functionality is not broken you need to have unit tests and preferably possibly system tests for you projects.